# Create a Map which maps enum

Tags: java, collections, enums, maps, java-stream

Need your help. I had a coding interview today and had this question.

Please complete the following snippet to create a Map which maps enum to edit privilege

```
Map<String, Boolean> userTypeToEditPermission () {
return Stream.____(UserType.____).____(____(Enum::name,UserType::hasEsitPermission));

enum UserType {
      ADMIN(true), MODERATOR(true), DEVELOPER(false);
}

private final boolean editPermission;

UserType(boolean editPermission) {
     this.editPermission=editPermission
}

public boolean hasEditPermission() {
return hasEditPermission;
}
```

Comment: What is your question actually? Please, be specific with questions on SO

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your snippet, the enum should probably look like this:

```java
enum UserType {
    ADMIN(true), MODERATOR(true), DEVELOPER(false);

    private final boolean editPermission;

    UserType(final boolean editPermission) {
        this.editPermission = editPermission;
    }

    public boolean hasEditPermission() {
        return editPermission;
    }
}
```

When it comes to the `userTypeToEditPermission()` method, I assume they want a mapping from the `UserType` name (`Enum::name`) to `editPermission` (`UserType::hasEditPermission`), which you can create as follows:

```java
return Stream.of(UserType.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Enum::name, UserType::hasEditPermission));
```

This creates a stream over all `UserType` values and then creates the aforementioned mapping:

```
{DEVELOPER=false, ADMIN=true, MODERATOR=true}
```